# Как изменить иконки интерфейсов в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, интерфейс

Суть проблемы: какое-то время работал в Intellij Idea  и перешел на Visual Studio 2017. Интерфейсы в шарпе пишутся начиная с "I" , но как визуально отличить класс от интерфейса как Идеи? Как можно изменить иконку с интерфейсами? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот вас тоже посещает мысль что странно что разработчики не умеют соединять качество и дизайн? Или одно, или другое...

Comment: На скриноште VS показаны _файлы_. В C# один файл может содержать не один, а много классов, интерфейсов и другого. Поэтому иконка всегда одна: иконка _файла_. Кликните на стрелочку, разверните содержимое - и увидите иконки классов, интерфейсов и т. п.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, изменить не получится, но отличить можно. Если "открыть" c#-файл, то в нем не только можно отличить классы и интерфейсы, но и методы, свойства, события, ...
[image: Иконки]

Смотри здесь: 
[Class View and Object Browser icons](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Если вам прям так нужны иконки Intellij Idea, то посмотрите на продукт от этой компании для студии, называется ReSharper.

Если зайти в настройки (`ReSharper` - `Options...`), то можно заметить пункт под названием `Source code symbols theme`, в котором можно выбрать интересующие вас иконки.

[image: Icons]

Правда не совсем они, да и применяются они только в подсказках IntelliSense, но для каждого удобство свое, может для вас этот вариант будет привычней.

[image: IntelliSense]

Comment: Тогда уж Rider взять вместо VS

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ну вопрос все же про VS, я лишь делюсь тем, что знаю. Для меня лично вообще не понятен вопрос по выбору иконок, ибо привыкнуть к новым иконкам для меня лично не составит труда. Но все мы разные...